# AngularJS app page path

Tags: angularjs

I am building my first AngularJS App and Im wondering why I can only access the URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/app/EventDetails.html
```

Shouldn't I be able to access it like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/EventDetails.html
```

There must be a setting somewhere but I'm not sure where to look

Comment: Not so much a setting as how you organize your files. If the EventDetails.html file is in a folder called app then you have to access it as your first URL. If it in the root of your webserver then you can access it as your second url.